# Connection string for using SQLite with ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project requiring interaction with a database. Therefore, I want to use SQLite with my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I have found some blogs and websites demonstrating some connection strings required to attach SQLite from ASP.NET MVC, but those are very old fashioned (about 6 years old).

So, my question is: what connection string is required in `web.config` to attach a SQLite database file to my ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Also what are the prerequisites for attaching SQLite with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Comment: Basically C# doesn't support Sqlite itself so we need a third-party DLL to connect to a (Sqlite database)[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5d065a/how-to-use-and-connect-sqlite-in-a-window-application/].

Comment: so why just sql lite..why not the inuilt sql express

Comment: I don't want to attach SQL Server, Express or LocalDB. Because my client(s) may want to deploy this application on his local server. It will be a problematic situation for him to control and configure Express or any other one in the future. SQLite does't required any installation, configuration and any other thing.

Comment: What is the target platform for the asp.net app? Win, MacOS or linux?

Comment: It can be change but mostly it will be run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For `ASP.NET Core 2.0`, modifications to `todo` web-api example: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api#create-the-project. A thorough description will be large, but should contain main items to be done.

- In file `appsettings.json` add entry with

  ```json
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=mydb.sqlite"
  }
  ```
- In `Startup.cs` modify method `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` with:

  ```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

      Configuration = builder.Build();
      string ConnectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
      services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(ConnectionStr));
      SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

      services.AddMvc();
  }
  ```
- In `Startup.cs` section `using` add

  ```cs
  using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
  using SQLitePCL;
  ```

Comment: OK, It maybe right way to add SQLite for Core applications and I also find some examples on some websites about Core 1 and Core 2. But I am not using Core at this time. My problem is to connect SQLite with MVC 5. Not connecting it with Core.

Comment: Great. I don't know the difference compared to MVC 5, but used net core 2.0 for the most up-to-date version. Some take aways from this solution could be, that Sqlite is integrated and works with asp.net framework. So maybe some starting points for some type of backwards migration.

Comment: Even with an answer set, exits possibilities to add more answers. So I you manage to setup Sqlite with MVC 5, then it is possible to upgrade with an extra more MVC 5 spefic answer.

Comment: It means there is no any way to connect SQlite with MVC 5...??? What do you say...???

Comment: I don't know, but asp.net and sqlite on SO doesn't seems as high traffic. Maybe more hits on e.g. https://forums.asp.net